# Applescript to automatically close dialog box after input?

Tags: events, dialog, applescript, handler, voice-recognition

Ok, so I am writing an applescript to do some voice control actions for me.

I am using Dragon Dictate 2.0 for mac for my voice control and mainly applescript for my coding. I have everything pretty much squared away except for once small issue. When expecting a voice command, I have applescript display a dialog for the text to be dictated into.

eg.

```
set cmd1 to the text returned of (display dialog "Speak Command:" default answer "")
```

This displays a dialog box with an empty text field, and the buttons "cancel" and "ok"

My problem is how I can press ok without having to speak an additional phrase. 
Currently I have a voice command that listens for me to speak "go" and then runs an applescript that presses the "return" key. This works, but I don't want to have to have to say "go".

I know I can add

```
giving up after 10
```

to automatically close the dialog box and accept the input after a certain time period, but there has to be a better way.

I have done some research and found that I could have an event handler for "on done editing" to execute a return keystroke. But I have no idea how to do this. If anyone has any input or ideas that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How would I do something similar? When the dictation is on the command window is disabled, therefore I can't say go to get the text of the speech. Is it because I don't use Dragon Dictate?

Comment: Also, if possible, it would be really great if I could see the code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "on done editing" is the best way but then you would have to write your dialog box in Xcode using objective-c or AppleScriptObjC. It seems that is beyond your abilities.

Something that might be within your abilities... you could simulate your own "on done editing" method. You could have a second applescript launch when your first applescript which shows the dialog box is run. This second applescript could check the text field of the dialog box periodically. When the text stops changing for a certain length of time then it could press the return key. It's a little complicated because you have to figure out how to target your dialog box from the second applescript, but it wouldn't be too hard. It might be best to give your dialog box a title, and then use system events to find the window with that title.

The reason you have to do this in a separate applescript is because your normal applescript pauses all commands while the dialog box is open. So you need a separate process running to check the text field and a second script would be the easiest way.

***EDIT***: Here's how to do it with applescript. First create this script which is your on done editing script. It will dismiss your dialog when the user stops entering text. Save it as a script called onDoneEditing to your desktop.

```
set shortDelay to 0.5
set longDelay to 1

delay longDelay --delay for a moment to let the dialog box from the first script launch

tell application "System Events"
    set theProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
    tell theProcess
        set dialogWindow to first window

        -- this repeat loop looks for when the user starts entering text into the dialog box
        repeat
            -- get the current text field value
            set currentValue to value of first text field of dialogWindow

            -- if the value has changed we know text is being entered
            if currentValue is not "" then exit repeat

            delay shortDelay
        end repeat

        -- this repeat loop looks for when the user stops entering text
        -- we know that when the text is the same after 2 checks
        delay longDelay
        repeat
            set newValue to value of first text field of dialogWindow

            if newValue is currentValue then
                keystroke return
            else
                set currentValue to newValue
            end if

            delay longDelay
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Now create this script. This script will launch the above script using the command line tool "osascript" so that it runs in a background process. Then it shows the dialog box for you. You can read my comments in both scripts to understand how each works.

```
-- launch the onDoneEditing script
-- we get the process id (thePID) of the launched process so we can kill it later
set onDoneEditing to (path to desktop as text) & "onDoneEditing.scpt"
set thePID to do shell script "osascript " & quoted form of POSIX path of onDoneEditing & " > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"

-- diaplay the dialog and make sure it will be frontmost
tell me to activate
display dialog "Speak Command:" default answer ""

-- kill the onDoneEditing to make sure it's not still running
try
    do shell script "kill " & thePID
end try
```

Comment: I have Xcode I just haven't had the time to teach myself objective-c yet. Do you know how it can be done with objective C? If you could provide me with code that would be a great starting point. I understand what you are saying with the applescript, the only problem is I am not sure how to check the text field of the dialog box periodically.

Comment: The other problem is that once a dialog box is shown. All other scripts currently running in the background or simaltaneously halt until the dialogue box is dismissed.

Comment: I edited the above with an applescript solution as I explained. You don't want to use objective-c because it's too complicated for you. You'd not only need to learn objective-c but also how to use interface builder to create the dialog window. There's no reason to learn all that because applescript works just fine. Let me know how it works!