# Applescript to click Done when dictating (Mac)

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a script that opens "Dictation & Speech", activates it (turns Dictation: On) and runs a shortcut to start dictating (System Events keystrokes Command D). All this works fine, but what I want to do is for it to click done (or the return key) after speech is not heard. I tried someone's answer from StackOverflow.

Here is the link: [Applescript to automatically close dialog box after input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838912/applescript-to-automatically-close-dialog-box-after-input)

But when it's done editing and the return key is pressed, there is no text entered. Maybe the return key is not pressed, and it just quits the dictation?

EDIT: After some research, I found out that the Dictation Window (or tiny Microphone Popup) will close if clicked anywhere except Done. So I am guessing when the Keystroke Return happens, it is on a different window, so I was wondering how would I get the current window/pop-up then click the Done key in it?

Comment: Post some of your code so we can see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Grigor how are you launching dictation automatically from a script that is a problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Done button is `button 1 of process "DictationIM"`:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "DictationIM"
    click button 1
end tell
```

Comment: This looks the cleanest and easiest method. Ill give it a try. Thanks a bunch and i will reward the bounty once it does what it describes. Also, how do you get the process name? Is there list of processes or you kinda have to know?

Comment: It worked. Would you be kind to answer my question in the comment above?

Comment: You can see them from Activity Monitor (after changing My Processes to All Processes) or with something like `ps -ef` or `pgrep -li dictat`.

Comment: I am getting this error: Can’t get button 1 of process "DictationIM". Invalid index. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are running a script or why you are not happy with it.

I have Dictation and Speech turned on in System Preferences with the shortcut "Press Left Command Key Twice". (You can set your own custom shortcut.) When I press the command key twice then the dictation service activates.  I can terminate the dictation service by pressing the return key and the text of whatever I was dictating is inserted wherever the cursor is.  This sounds like exactly what you want, so why do you need the script?

Comment: OK, I see.  I don't know how you are detecting that speech is not heard, but pressing the return key should work for terminating dictation.

Comment: When i programmed it to do that it closed the popup instead of clicking djne to process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "click" on the button with applescript like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
    tell theProcess
        click button "Done" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to repeat the command-D keystroke.
thats all. you are able to start dictation with command-D so you are able to exit dictation with command-D

Comment: I am getting this error: Can’t get button 0 of process "DictationIM". Invalid index. any idea?